# Can not a bash function using "unset -f" when function name is provided as a variable in a loop

Tags: bash, unset

I am trying to unset function using be searching for all of them and then looping to unset them with no luck

Non loop way works (example where bar_ is created and unset)

```
function bar_ { echo "bar"; }
function_name="bar_"
echo -n "before unset found function: --> "
declare -F $function_name || echo "<not found>"
unset -f $function_name
echo -n "after unset found function: --> "
declare -F $function_name || echo "<not found>"
echo ""
```

However when unsetting in  a loop, it fails to remove itself

```
function foo_ { echo "bar"; }
declare -F | cut -d" " -f3 | grep foo_ | while read function_name
do
    echo -n "before under found function: --> "
    declare -F $function_name || echo "<not found>"
    unset -f ${function_name}
done
echo -n "after unset found function: --> "
declare -F foo_ || echo "<not found>"
echo ""
```

Is this some scope issue? I tried wrapping the unset statement in eval to no effect.

Comment: What's up with the semicolons and backslashes at the end of every line?

Comment: I'm curious: what is your requirement to do this in the first place? :)

Comment: the semicolons and backslahses just so it would be easy to run the test I was doing in one easy to copy-paste line.

Comment: the requirement is to destroy functions that were sourced. There are too many to manually keep a list ... so they are identified by a pattern in a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the loop, but the pipe. Try it this way:

```
function foo_ {
 echo "bar"
}

while read function_name
do
    echo -n "before under found function: --> "
    declare -F $function_name || echo "<not found>"
    unset -f ${function_name}
done <  <( declare -F | cut -d" " -f3 | grep foo_ )

echo -n "after unset found function: --> "
declare -F foo_ || echo "<not found>"
echo ""
```

This uses bash process substitution.
Alternatively you could use a temporary file or a coprocess here.

Comment: thank you. that solves exactly right. totally blanked on the pipe being a subshell

Answer (score 1):

When you have a pipeline, the pipeline is in a subshell and cannot affect the outer shell, variable-wise.  Very annoying at times.

Your solution: output the commands (echo "unset -f $function_name") and then eval the output of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Bash builtin `compgen` you could avoid the subshell issue.

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
unset -f $(compgen -A function foo_)
```

On a related note you may turn off function lookup for a single command by using `env -i`.

```
ls() { echo 'Hello, world!'; }

ls

env -i ls
```